# How can I find out the md5sum of boot-repair-disk.ISO?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, boot-repair

I have downloaded boot-repair-disk.ISO, but it is recommended to check the md5sum. Previous downloads have not worked possibly because the download was corrupted. At present running  Kubuntu 16.04 on Live USB on dual boot with Windows 7, which screwed up booting when I tried upgrade to W10

Comment: That's actually my first thing not to do when dual-booting W10. The bootloader needs to go to an external Disk to leave the Windows untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Together with the download you should have had an offer to download the checksum file. In case of that you have a checksum file you would call:

```bsh
# change according to how the sum file is called and make sure both are in the same directory
md5sum -c boot-repair-disk.ISO.sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you burn the iso into an usb, open up the console in usb path.
You will find a file called md5sum.txt

run md5sum -c md5sum.txt and it will check every folder in USB drive, it will display a message for every folder

In this example some folders don-t match

```
./README.diskdefines: La suma coincide
./pics/blue-lowerright.png: La suma coincide
./pics/blue-upperleft.png: La suma coincide
./pics/logo-50.jpg: La suma coincide
./pics/debian.jpg: La suma coincide
./pics/blue-upperright.png: La suma coincide
./pics/blue-lowerleft.png: La suma coincide
./pics/red-lowerleft.png: La suma coincide
./pics/red-upperright.png: La suma coincide
./pics/red-upperleft.png: La suma coincide
./pics/red-lowerright.png: La suma coincide
./install/README.sbm: La suma coincide
./install/sbm.bin: La suma coincide
./install/mt86plus: La suma coincide
./boot/grub/loopback.cfg: La suma coincide
./boot/grub/grub.cfg: La suma coincide
./EFI/BOOT/bootia32.efi: La suma coincide
./dists/bionic/multiverse/binary-i386/Release: La suma coincide
./dists/bionic/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz: La suma coincide
./dists/bionic/Release.gpg: La suma coincide
./dists/bionic/restricted/binary-i386/Release: La suma coincide
./dists/bionic/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz: La suma coincide
./dists/bionic/Release: La suma coincide
./dists/bionic/main/binary-i386/Release: La suma coincide
./dists/bionic/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz: La suma coincide
./dists/bionic/universe/binary-i386/Release: La suma coincide
./dists/bionic/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz: La suma coincide
./pool/main/m/mouseemu/mouseemu_0.16-0ubuntu10_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/m/make-dfsg/make_4.1-9.1ubuntu1_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/s/setserial/setserial_2.17-50_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/h/hw-detect/archdetect-deb_1.117ubuntu6.18.04.1_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/libf/libfile-fcntllock-perl/libfile-fcntllock-perl_0.22-3build2_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/libd/libdebian-installer/libdebian-installer4_0.110ubuntu2_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/u/ubiquity/ubiquity_18.04.14.15_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/u/ubiquity/oem-config_18.04.14.15_all.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/u/ubiquity/oem-config-gtk_18.04.14.15_all.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/u/ubiquity/ubiquity-frontend-gtk_18.04.14.15_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/u/ubiquity/ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork_18.04.14.15_all.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/u/user-setup/user-setup_1.63ubuntu5_all.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/r/rdate/rdate_1.2-6_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/libt/libtimezonemap/libtimezonemap-data_0.4.5_all.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/libt/libtimezonemap/libtimezonemap1_0.4.5_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/libt/libtimezonemap/gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0_0.4.5_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/libx/libxklavier/gir1.2-xkl-1.0_5.4-3_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/n/network-manager/gir1.2-nm-1.0_1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/n/network-manager-applet/gir1.2-nma-1.0_1.8.10-2ubuntu3_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/i/ido/libido3-0.1-0_13.10.0+17.04.20161028-0ubuntu1_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/j/json-glib/gir1.2-json-1.0_1.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/p/pptp-linux/pptp-linux_1.9.0+ds-2_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/p/python-pam/python3-pam_0.4.2-13.2ubuntu4_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/p/pyicu/python3-icu_1.9.8-0ubuntu1_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/d/dpkg-repack/dpkg-repack_1.43_all.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/d/dpkg/libdpkg-perl_1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3_all.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/a/apt-clone/apt-clone_0.4.1ubuntu2_all.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/c/cryptsetup/cryptsetup_2.0.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/c/cryptsetup/cryptsetup-bin_2.0.2-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/c/casper/ubiquity-casper_1.394.3_all.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/main/l/lupin/lupin-support_0.57build1_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/universe/g/grub2/grub2_2.02-2ubuntu8.17_i386.deb: La suma coincide
./pool/universe/c/caspar/caspar_20170830-1_all.deb: La suma coincide
./.disk/cd_type: La suma coincide
./.disk/base_installable: La suma coincide
./.disk/casper-uuid-generic: La suma coincide
./.disk/release_notes_url: La suma coincide
./.disk/info: La suma coincide
./casper/filesystem.squashfs.gpg: La suma coincide
./casper/filesystem.manifest: La suma coincide
./casper/filesystem.size: La suma coincide
./casper/filesystem.squashfs: La suma no coincide
./casper/initrd: La suma coincide
./casper/filesystem.manifest-remove: La suma coincide
./casper/vmlinuz: La suma coincide
./casper/filesystem.manifest-minimal-remove: La suma coincide
./preseed/cli.seed: La suma coincide
./preseed/lubuntu.seed: La suma coincide
md5sum: ATENCIÓN: 1 suma calculada NO coincidió
```